# length function without recursion ocaml

Tags: ocaml, computer-science

I'm trying to rewrite the `List.length` function without using recursion. Here's my code:

```
(* given *)
type 'a list =
  | []
  | (::) of 'a * 'a list
let nil : 'a list = []
let cons (hd : 'a) (tl : 'a list): 'a list = hd :: tl

let length (ls : 'a list): int =
  let i = fold_left(fun x y -> Fun.const 1 :: y) [] ls in
  fold_left(fun x y -> x + y) 0 i
```

OCaml gave me an error on the last line `fold_left(fun x y -> x + y) 0 i` and saying my `i` here has `type ('a -> int) list` but an expression was expected of `type int list`, is there any way I can fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Try `1 :: y` instead of `Fun.const 1 :: y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve with `Fun.const`, but you can actually achieve `length` with a single `fold_left`:

```ml
let length l =
  fold_left (fun acc _ -> acc+1) 0 l
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your attempt.

As `Fun.const` creates in this case a function which always returns `1`, and your expression parses as: `(Fun.const 1) :: y` your first use of `List.fold_left` is generating a list of functions which all return one. But there are *not* the value `1`.

Thus when you use `fold_left (fun x y -> x + y) 0 i` you are trying to add a function to an int. Clearly this doesn't work. You need to *apply* some argument to that function.

```
let length (ls : 'a list): int =
  let i = List.fold_left(fun x y -> Fun.const 1 :: y) [] ls in
  List.fold_left(fun x y -> x + y ()) 0 i
```

This compiles. *But...* the type doesn't look quite right.

```
val length : (unit -> int) list list -> int = <fun>
```

This results from having the argument order to the function `List.fold_left` takes wrong. The first argument is the initial value. The second is the first element from the list.

If we change that:

```
let length (ls : 'a list): int =
  let i = List.fold_left (fun y _ -> Fun.const 1 :: y) [] ls in
  List.fold_left (fun x y -> x + y ()) 0 i
```

The type of this function is:

```
val length : 'a list -> int = <fun>
```

But as [Blackbeans has noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74177999/15261315), there is a much simpler way to write this using a single call to `List.fold_left`.